# How is the question/answer on the tour page chosen?

Tags: support

On the [tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) page under the heading *Ask questions, get answers, no distractions* there is a question, and my answer appears underneath.

How is the question chosen? I have no objection to my answer being there, just wondering whether it is automated or manually chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a recent short question with multiple short answers and not much formatting.

[What determines the questions available for selection in the tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-tour-page)